# Cascode MOSFET Vds

Tags: mosfet, amplifier, analog, integrated-circuit

[image]

Hi, I am having some difficulty understanding the statement underlined. How does M2 see Vb-Vth2 across its drain source?

Comment: I suspect some careless editing and they meant Vth of transistor M3.

Answer (score 0):

> *How does M2 see Vb-Vth2 across its drain source?*

M3 is a source follower so M2's drain voltage is largely dictated by \$V_b\$ minus the gate-source threshold voltage of M2. It's approximate of course.

<sub>Vth2 is not defined in the question but is assumed to equal \$V_{GS(TH)}\$ of M3.</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Assumptions

- Vdd is some voltage >1V
- M2 & M3 are similar but not necessarily exactly the same
- When Vgs2 is = Vth2 or slightly higher it will control the current shared by M3
- in order for both to be in the linear range and share current, each Vgs must be at the required voltage to share the same current and produce some Vds drop
- if Vth2 is not = Vth3 this difference will be added to Vgs2 and thus Vb so that it tracks the same current.
- Vb > Vth2+Vth3
- Vd3 will be constant controlled by M2 gate’s constant current

Conclusion

Vds2 must follow Vb-Vth2 and track the differences in Vth2 & Vth3

- therefore Vgs3 must = Vgs2 +(Vth3-Vth2)
- Thus the assertion that Vds2 follows Vb-Vth2 is incorrect unless both have identical thresholds